# How can we collect the facebook group request data using a chrome extension?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, graph

Is there any way that we can collect data by asking the questions when someone wants to join the group. And we collect the data when we approve the joining request or sometimes programmatically?

Could you please elaborate on how we can use Facebook GRAPH API for fulfilling the above purpose?

Comment: You can’t, this stuff is not available via API.

Comment: Yes, I know. Is there any other way @CBroe?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GroupTrack CRM](https://www.grouptrackcrm.com)...it's a CRM that is integrated into Facebook via a Chrome Extension. It does exactly what you asked (one click to approve individual or all pending members while also saving their answers to your questions and adding them to the CRM), along with a ton of other awesome stuff.

Keep notes and tags, track sales funnel stages, bookmark posts and comments, set follow up tasks with reminders, and more across unlimited Groups. Everything is synced in real time with a web app as well, so you can access your contact information from anywhere, plus it can be set up to integrate with external systems (Google Sheets, Streak, and Kartra at the moment, but many more to come).

Lastly, GroupTrack supports teams, so if you run a Group with other admins, you can share access to the CRM and have everything kept in sync. It's awesome!